# Where can I find credentials for `magento-cloud auth:api-token-login`

Tags: magento2-cloud

As the title suggest. I am using below command for Magento Cloud CLI tool (https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/reference/cli-ref-topic.html)

```
magento-cloud auth:api-token-login
```

It asks for:

```
Please enter an API token:
>
```

Where can I find this "API token"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently it can be found here:

https://accounts.magento.cloud/ login with Magento/Adobe account (or request password when it is the first time)

Then navigate

```
Tab "Account settings" > API Tokens
```

Add API token and you're done.

Comment: Then set it as `MAGENTO_CLOUD_CLI_TOKEN` shell variable locally so you don't need to paste it everytime